# JavaScript and CSS dynamic versioning

Tags: javascript

I had a question regarding dynamic versioning of JavaScript and CSS file references in HTML files. For example:

```
script src = "test.js?v=1234"
```

And similarly with CSS references. I have done this in the past using ASP.NET, where I can call a function from the server side to generate a random number everytime the page loads ex:

```
"test.js?v=<%= myrandomfunc() %>"
```

I basically don't want the browser to get a cached copy of the css or js reference. I wanted to know if I can do this in JavaScript or jquery without using a server side language like asp or php etc.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted to know if I can do this in JavaScript or jquery without
>   using a server side language like asp or php etc.

Yes.

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.onload = function() {
  //do your stuff here
};
script.src = "http://whatever.com/the/script.js?v="+(+new Date());
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

[Another](https://public-bn1306.files.1drv.com/y3pz4gRTRAol65370nX8mQevjIgwVcgJ8w24EBNdshnvxgYs6_D6LPuFC0BUB_abS-6AGeuGjEyJH89rgY2ZpvN0-0QIA8n_P7dIdwEURiKp48/SetExpireDate.png?psid=1&rdrts=114272645) option is to send the right headers :

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll give it a try.

Comment: That JS “solution” will make any sensible form of caching impossible.

Comment: @CBroe He doesn't want caching at all.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: That’s what the question might read like, but I am not sure if that’s really what the OP _wants_.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I don't want caching at all.

Comment: @ParikshitBhagawati You can add header to the server for JS files. ( that was my second option).

Answer (score 0):

This is called *file revving* and it depends on what build system you're using. For Grunt, there's [grunt-filerev](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-filerev), for Gulp, there's [gulp-rev](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-rev) and [gulp-filerev-replace](https://github.com/solidusjs/gulp-filerev-replace).

If you don't yet use a build system, you might also want to check out [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) which will generate just about everything you need, including file revving.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have seen some solutions related to the grunt system which I don't have much knowledge about. I was hoping basically for a client side solution rather that configuring the system. But it seems interesting and I'll be sure to look into it. So thanks again !