# How to version JavaScript and CSS files efficiently?

Tags: javascript, css, assets

I have lots of CSS and JavaScript files. Currently I maintain versioning using something that looks like this:

```
modal.js?v=1.0.0
form.js?v=1.0.0
table.js?v=1.0.0
style.css?v=1.0.0
```

These files are loaded in multiple HTML files. When I need to change version I manually go to every HTML file and change the path like this `modal.js?v=1.0.1`. But it's a headache to change every files every time.
I can do versioning dynamically like this

```
modal.js?v=<script>(new Date()).getTime();</script>
```

But I have a problem here: I use file caching. I need to cache files only when the file version is updated, otherwise use old cached files.

I already tried  these but they do not fulfill my requirements:

- [JavaScript and CSS dynamic versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32025576/javascript-and-css-dynamic-versioning)
- https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-force-the-browser-to-reload-cached-js-css-files-to-reflect-latest-chan/

Comment: Are the HTML files static? You’ll probably need to switch to templates regardless of the approach. (That doesn’t necessarily mean introducing a server-side language – you can create static HTML files from templates as a build step *you* run before publishing.)

Comment: I use with Django so all files included in template.

Comment: In that case, IIRC you want https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#manifeststaticfilesstorage.

Comment: I tried this. But the problem is, it cached all the files again. But I only need to re-cached updated files, not every file.

Comment: It’s just a one-time thing.

Comment: Ok. I will try again.

Comment: The [module](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#manifeststaticfilesstorage) looks like it uses a hash of the file to generate the URL, so it wouldn't force redownloads of unchanged files anyway.